# Product two 3D tensor in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have two tensor with 3 dimensions:

```
 tensor 1 (bs1, sent_len1, emb_dim)
 tensor 2 (bs2, sent_len2, emb_dim)
```

bs1 and bs2 are unknown and they are not necessarily equal.

I want to product these tensors to get an output like this:

```
 output (bs1, bs2, sent_len2, sent_len1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using K.dot() like this:

```
t2t = K.permute_dimensions(tensor2, [0, 2, 1])  # (bs2, emb_dim, sent_len2)
output = K.dot(tensor1, t2t)  # (bs1, sent_len1, bs2, sent_len2)
```